# After kept back packages, AppCenter deleted VLC

Tags: vlc, package

During a manual update last week, I saw some mesa-related packages kept back, but I dind't do anything about it. Yesterday I updated via AppCenter and today I've discovered that VLC is missing. Now I want to recover it, but when I try to install it I get the following message:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be 
installed or libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have little experience in fixing broken/kept-back packages. Any recommendation?

Comment: What ppa did you install? hmm

Comment: I can't remeber adding any ppa recently. In fact, I have the same problem in my office's computer, and it's quite unlikely that I installed something there like I would do at home.

Comment: Well, the other option is to manually install those packages. `sudo apt install vlc  libgles1-mesa libgles1` . If executing that tells you its going to remove lots of files, dont do it.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, and the errors keep going on: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgles1-mesa : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try [the first answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940320/apt-wants-to-uninstall-vlc-because-libgles1-is-too-old-even-though-the-vlc-team) . It may solve it